# Best practice - Forking dependency within large framework

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

I'm using Sails for a project.
I have to make a change to connect which is a dependency of express, which is a dependency of Sails.

So obviously I could fork connect, but then that would require a change to Express's package.json, which I believe would require forking Express, then sails, etc, correct?

Hopefully I'm missing something! :)

Basically I have to change the path of the file requested based on a header variable, but I don't want the client to know of the change. I don't think this can be done via middleware with Connect+Express, but it would be cool if I was wrong!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: If I'm understanding what you're asking, it certainly **can** be done via middleware, very easily.  Can you elaborate why you think it can't?

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot. I added the middleware in the wrong place in Sails. Adding it directly to Express works fine.

Thanks! :D